# Inversion Region

Tags: transistors, nmos, pmos

If one transistor in a circuit (say common source with active load) operate at the strong inversion region, should the rest of the transistor also operate on that same region? Or will it depend?

Comment: I like to make logic inverters. The other transistor should be in cutoff. Perhaps you need to add more information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't assume all the FETs in a circuit operate in the same mode.

Each FET operates in the mode determined by the potentials at its terminals.

In a simple analog amplifier it's likely that the designer arranged that many of the FETs will normally be operating in the saturation region. But in a CMOS digital gate it's likely that the designer would arrange for some devices to operate in the triode or saturation region while others are in cut-off.